# Laravel: Joining multiple select statements

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a survey app.
Each `SurveyResponse` has multiple `QuestionResponses`.
For reporting purposes I want to filter the `QuestionResponses` based on values answered for other `QuestionResponses` that are part of the same `SurveyResponse` - eg. Give me all the question responses of those that selected `Male` for the `Gender`question.

The following example SQL query is working, but I am struggling to replicate it in Laravel:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT * 
       FROM question_responses ) AS A

JOIN ( SELECT survey_response_id AS JOIN_A
       FROM question_responses
       WHERE (question_short_name = 'Gender') AND (value = 'Male')) AS B
ON A.survey_response_id= JOIN_A) AS C

JOIN ( SELECT survey_response_id AS JOIN_B
       FROM question_responses
       WHERE (question_short_name = 'Age') AND (value = '45 to 54')) AS D
ON C.survey_response_id=JOIN_B
```

How would I do this using Eloquent or Laravel's query builder?

Comment: are you correct with those multiple selects ?

Comment: In laravel 5.7, you can use `selectRaw()` method to execute raw SQL queries. [Ref](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DB::select` method to retrieve result.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


$results = DB::select("SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT * 
   FROM question_responses ) AS A
JOIN ( SELECT survey_response_id AS JOIN_A
   FROM question_responses
   WHERE (question_short_name = ?) AND (value = ?)) AS B
ON A.survey_response_id= JOIN_A) AS C
JOIN ( SELECT survey_response_id AS JOIN_B
   FROM question_responses
   WHERE (question_short_name = ?) AND (value = ?)) AS D
ON C.survey_response_id= JOIN_B", ['Gender', 'Male', 'Age', '45 to 54']);

foreach ($results as $key => $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the eloquent relationship, but if you want to use this particular type of query then you can use the DB class in laravel.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$data = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT * 
       FROM question_responses ) AS A

JOIN ( SELECT survey_response_id AS JOIN_A
       FROM question_responses
       WHERE (question_short_name = 'Gender') AND (value = 'Male')) AS B
ON A.survey_response_id= JOIN_A.your_id) AS C

JOIN ( SELECT survey_response_id AS JOIN_B
       FROM question_responses
       WHERE (question_short_name = 'Age') AND (value = '45 to 54')) AS D
ON C.survey_response_id=JOIN_B.your_id'))
```

after getting the response you can retrieve the data by $data[0]['key'] for using '->' or making it collection you can use the Collection class.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

$tempData = Collection::make(DB::select(DB::raw('select query'));
($tempData[0])->key;
```

Comment: quick dirty way :)